# Radiant R not working on shiny server

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny, ubuntu-14.04, shiny-server

As per given instruction on the [website](http://vnijs.github.io/radiant/), I installed the Radiant package on Ubuntu server with the following command.

```
install.packages("radiant", repos = "https://radiant-rstats.github.io/minicran/")
```

Then cloned the repo from [here](https://github.com/vnijs/radiant/) and placed it in the /srv/shiny server/ folder of shiny server.

I can run radiant from addins and from within RStuodio, however as soon as I point my browser to ipaddress:3838/inst/app I get the following error in the browser.

```
An error has occurred
The application failed to start.
The application exited during initialization.
```

The shiny server log produces the following error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘shiny’ 0.14.2 is already loaded, but >= 1.0 is required
Calls: runApp ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

I checked the shiny version, it is indeed the latest version, I'm not able to identify the problem, any help.

Comment: i am not an expert with the ubuntu R combination. But maybe a few ideas: Check `.libPaths()` if you have somewhere an old version of shiny installed or in general multiple library paths. For some packages i remember it helped installing them outside R. And for sure i would add the ubuntu tag to the question. good luck!

Comment: Thanks BigDataScientist, I updated my shiny package from command line (which user shiny access) and it started working. Thank you.

Comment: nice! Thats just what i remembered from my research when i encountered similar problems. If you dont mind i add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like i mentioned in the comments, often it helps to install the package outside R (from command line). If you have the package locally available you can use `R CMD INSTALL shiny_1.0.3.tar.gz`. If you dont have it locally available you could download it with e.g `wget` from `https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/shiny_1.0.3.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 1):

It´s been a while so I wonder if you fixed the issue in any case there are some new versions of the package that might help. I suggest the following:

- Follow the most up to date version at http://vnijs.github.io/radiant/
- Try installing directly in the R console without going inside Rstudio o Rstudio server.

Hope that helps!

Cheers!